# Show only one row from mysql based on usertype

Tags: php, mysql

I've made login form where when user log I store in `SESSION` his credentials. One of the row is `usertype` which is unique for each user. Now I have two tables. Table `users`

```
id
...
usertype
```

second table is `hauses` which also has row `usertype`.

Third table is `user_hauses`

```
hause_usertype
user_usertype
```

Now I've trying when user with `usertype=1` log to store this `1` into session and when click on `Hauses` button to load only that row from DB which is with `usertype=1`. Tried with this query but didn't work so far.

```
$q = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `houses` AS c
                   LEFT JOIN `user_hauses` AS h2u ON c.hause_id = r2u.user_id
                   LEFT JOIN `users` AS u ON h2u.user_id = u.usertype");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like a typo, see end of 2nd line change r2u to h2u

```
$q = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `houses` AS c
                   LEFT JOIN `user_hauses` AS h2u ON c.hause_id = h2u.user_id
                   LEFT JOIN `users` AS u ON h2u.user_id = u.usertype");
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer typo is ok but is not only this. Something else is wrong `mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given`

Comment: var_dump($q) return `bool(false)` .. so somewhere I have other mistake but still can't see it.

Comment: Do I need to make foreign keys here on pivot table?

Comment: It's really hard to say without seeing more code. $con should be a valid connection to a database, if the connection fails that could be why it's a boolean value.

Comment: Another thing you could try is put the query in the "Query Browser" or use the MySQL "WorkBench" to test your queries.